# Show Jqueries errors without touching the code

Tags: jquery

I got a brand new template full os scripts, but there's no error in console (like 404, 403). Everything is fine but the Jqueries doesn't work.

Is there a way to bind Jquery errors and show them in console?

PS.: I did a quick search, however, it only talks about ajax errors.

**UPDATE 1**
Before someone throw me in the fire, here's a list of all scripts called after all html:

```
<script scr="<?echo base_url();?>js/jquery.2.2.3.min.js"></script> 
<script scr="<?echo base_url();?>js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script scr="<?echo base_url();?>js/jquery.appear.js"></script>
<script scr="<?echo base_url();?>js/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js"></script> 
<script scr="<?echo base_url();?>js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script scr="<?echo base_url();?>js/jquery.fancybox.js"></script> 
<script scr="<?echo base_url();?>js/cubeportfolio.min.js"></script> 
<script scr="<?echo base_url();?>js/range-Slider.min.js"></script> 
<script scr="<?echo base_url();?>js/selectbox-0.2.min.js"></script> 
<script scr="<?echo base_url();?>js/bootsnav.js"></script> 
<script scr="<?echo base_url();?>js/zelect.js"></script>
<script scr="<?echo base_url();?>js/videobox/video.js"></script>
<script scr="<?echo base_url();?>js/datepicker.js"></script> 
<script scr="<?echo base_url();?>js/dropzone.min.js"></script> 
<script scr="<?echo base_url();?>js/image-light-box.js"></script> 
<script scr="<?echo base_url();?>js/wow.min.js"></script> 
<script scr="<?echo base_url();?>js/form.js"></script> 
<script scr="<?echo base_url();?>js/custom-map.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAOBKD6V47-g_3opmidcmFapb3kSNAR70U"></script>
<script scr="<?echo base_url();?>js/gmaps.js"></script>
<script scr="<?echo base_url();?>js/contact.js"></script> 
<script scr="<?echo base_url();?>js/themepunch/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js"></script>
<script scr="<?echo base_url();?>js/themepunch/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>   
<script scr="<?echo base_url();?>js/themepunch/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js"></script> 
<script scr="<?echo base_url();?>js/themepunch/revolution.extension.navigation.min.js"></script> 
<script scr="<?echo base_url();?>js/themepunch/revolution.extension.parallax.min.js"></script> 
<script scr="<?echo base_url();?>js/themepunch/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js"></script> 
<script scr="<?echo base_url();?>js/themepunch/revolution.extension.video.min.js"></script>
<script scr="<?echo base_url();?>js/functions.js"></script>
<script scr="<?echo base_url();?>js/typed.min.js"></script>
```

I double checked the code. There's no error's and files are not missing.

This is way I'll like to know if there's a way to check all jquery erros on the page.

Comment: How do you know jquery is not working?

Comment: What did you search for when it only came uo with AJAX errors?

Comment: @Huangism because every Owl Slider and other Jquery script's doesn't work, but no console error. Very weird.

Comment: @putvande "show jquery errors". Wow that's nice, people are voting down this answer so quick but no response at all.

Comment: Do you have code you can show? You must be getting an error if you use jQuery and you haven't loaded it (properly).

Comment: @MarceloAgimóvel I imagine people are downvoting because your question don't involve any code and is kind of broad with no specifics. Have you tried to check if jquery is loaded in console? For example `$(window)` does that work on your site? When you inspect the source `<?echo base_url();?>` does this give you the correct path? Have you tried the entire path in a window to see if anything loads?

Comment: @putvande I'll update my question.

Comment: Is this your actual code? Try changing all the `scr` to `src`

Comment: @putvande I believe there was some invisible code, i did what you said and it's working. Would you like to post the answer so I can positive you?

Comment: I think you would of eventually caught this if you tried a little bit of debugging, could be why people are downvoting

Comment: @Huangism will you imagine that a template that work's would do that? I didint. But it did! And the crazy about this is that is all wrong in template, but he work's. However, if i start to change it, stop working. Should I delete my post in your opinion?

Comment: @MarceloAgimóvel the only thing that worked are the html and css, none of the js worked because they are not linked properly. It's up to you if you want to delete the question or not, personally I don't see any value in it because it was a typo that caused the error, but it is your decision

Comment: @Huangism I can submit to you the hole downloaded template, with the error and I can guarantee that will work even with scr instead of src. However, if you transform the template from HTML to PHP it will stop working.That's why I couldn't see the error. You want my user and password on ThemeForest to make sure I didin't changed anything and the template works? Fine, I can give it to you. Thank's for your help btw.

Comment: @MarceloAgimóvel you got nothing to prove to me, but I suggest you don't use `scr` in an interview and say that is correct

Answer (score 1):

Seems your `<script>` tags all have `scr` instead of `src`. Think if you change that, it should work.
Good to check your console in the 'network' tab to see if the page is actually loading all the assets you are expecting.